Is it possible to implement an ack mechanism similar to RabbitMQ using bullmq?
I need to implement a mechanism similar to RabbitMQ ack using bullmq:

When the worker processes a job, it launches another 'process'. This will create an event in an event emitter.
Once the worker process has finished, the job should not be marked as completed or failed.
The job is complete (as acknowledged by RabbitMQ) when the event is received.
If something goes wrong in the middle (e.g. the program stops), then the uncompleted jobs should be queued to be processed again.

Is there a way to do this with bullmq? I'm trying to solve this, but I haven't come up with any ideas.

I've tried this solution, but it's not working because sometimes I get the error job stalled more than allowable limit. The idea was to made available the resolve method of a promise outside of the worker, and call it in another function:
import { Worker } from 'bullmq'

const redisConfig = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 6379,
  username: 'default',
  password: 'whatever',
}
const QUEUE_NAME = 'exampleQueue'

function currentTime() {
  return new Date().toISOString()
}

const jobs = []

function createPromise(){
  let theResolve
  const promise = new Promise(resolve => { theResolve = resolve})
  promise.resolve = theResolve
  return promise
}

const _worker = new Worker(QUEUE_NAME, async job => {
  try {
    console.log(`${currentTime()} - Processing job ${job.id}`)

    const promise = createPromise()
    const pendingJob = {id: job.id, promise: promise}

    console.log('Adding job to pending list: ' + job.id)
    jobs.push(pendingJob)
    return await promise

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}, {
  connection: redisConfig,
})

setInterval(() => {
  console.log('Checking for pending jobs')
  const pendingJob = jobs.pop()
  if (!pendingJob) return

  const { id, promise } = pendingJob

  console.log(`Completing the job ${id} outside of the worker `)
  promise.resolve(currentTime())

}, 5000)

This is the code to add a job to the queue, in case you need to test:
let jobCounter = 1
async function addJob(queue) {
  const jobData = {
    counter: jobCounter++,
    attempts: 1
  }
  const job = await queue.add('exampleJob', jobData)
  console.log(`Added job ${job.id}`)
}

const queueEvents = new QueueEvents(QUEUE_NAME, {
  connection: redisConfig
})
queueEvents.on('completed', ({ jobId, returnvalue }) => {
  console.log(`Job ${jobId} has been completed with value ${returnvalue}`)
})

queueEvents.on('failed', async (job, _error) => {
  console.log(job)
  console.log(`*** Job with id ${job.jobId} has failed after all retry attempts.***`);
})


// Single job
addJob(queue)

Update: I've seen this way of manual processing the jobs, I think it could help. I'll try something with that.
